# Resources for Angular2

Tags: angular

I am having a hard time trying to find the resources for angular 2 in the web. I have been watching all the videos from conferences and other github repositories but nothing seemed to have proper information on the latest code examples or documentation. 
I think i am looking in the wrong places, if anyone can share any information on this it would be a life saver for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all you must understand that angular2 is not ready yet. It's in very active development at this moment. API is changing over time. So any resources can be out of date. And what you'll learn may not be useful in the future:(. But, anyway, if you want to start learning it now, first of all look at these to repos:

1. **https://github.com/angular-class/awesome-angular2**:
2. **https://github.com/timjacobi/angular2-education**:

There you can find a lot of resources to learn angular2

Small list from me:

- [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/) Of course the official website. It may be out of date, but it's the most trustworthy resource I think.
- [angular2.com](http://www.angular2.com/) List of resources for angular2 learning
- [learnangular2.com](http://learnangular2.com/) Small tutorial created by Ionic team
- [blog.thoughtram.io](http://blog.thoughtram.io/categories/angular-2/) List of really good articles about angular2. Most of them was written by Pascal Precht. Thanks him for that
- [victorsavkin.com](http://victorsavkin.com/) Blog of Victor Savkin (Core team member of angular2). Again, you can find really good articles here
- [Angular2 examples from official repository](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/examples/src) You can learn a lot just by looking on different examples
- [Angular2 authentication sample](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-authentication-sample) Authentication example made by auth0 team.

**UPD** Two more things. Thanks to Eric Martinez (@eric-martinez) for them!

- [syntaxsuccess.com](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/articleList/angular) Angular 2 articles in Torgeir Helgevold's blog
- [gitter.im/angular/angular](https://gitter.im/angular/angular) Angular2 gitter chat room. It's not a resource for learning, but you always can find help there. It's pretty active.

Comment: you could add http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/articleList/angular too, and I think the chatroom for ng2 should be added too. Personally I think it is almost essential.

Comment: @EricMartinez You're dead right! I updated the answer. Thanks!