# angularJs 2.0 start from scrach

Tags: javascript, angular

Since angularJS 2.0 is already around the cornor, I have been trying to look for a nice sample or excercise which at least touches the core of angularJS 2.0 features.

So far i have not found a good tuorial covering most of the things of angular JS 2.0 which can be used to build a real web APP in the coming day.

Can anyone share some resources which can be helpful?

Comment: https://egghead.io/technologies/angular2

Comment: @Mike would be great if something for free

Comment: most of the angular2 lessons are free

Comment: Just doing a little search... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539689/resources-for-angular2

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  My friend Dan Wahlin has some great videos on YouTube.  But with Angular 2.0 you should really become best friends with TypeScript along with JavaScript.

So things to learn traditionally are Javascript, then Angular...not add TypeScript ( which is a "user friendly" C# like wrapper around Javasrcipt ).

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/getting-started-with-typescript-classes-static-types-and-interfaces

Also...not plugging Plural sight BUT its a great resource and there is what you are looking for.

http://www.pluralsight.com/search/?searchTerm=Angular

Happy Coding